# Unable to find a way to access downloadable element from page

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I want to programmatically download CSV files from basketball-reference.com. The screenshot below shows how one would do it manually in-browser:

[image]

However, the page source for this element is as follows:

[image]

My first thought is this isn't scrapeable because it's behind some Javascript or something.  Is there a way I can get at this element?

UPDATE:  This also exists:

[image]

Can I have Selenium click this?

Comment: do you have the url?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click on that element and display the table you'd do something like this. But this only brings it up on the site so if you want to you can grab that or send a request to the page.

```
driver.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/')
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Share & more']/parent::li"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Get table as CSV (for Excel)']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'll look into adding these.  This looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Essentially, though, we know it's clickable via Selenium?

Comment: I got this:  ```ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="hasmore">...</li> is not clickable at point (239, 573). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_....```

Comment: In doing some more reading, it looks like this may be an Google Ad getting in the way.   So far, I'm unable to figure out how to remove it appropriately.

Comment: It is clickable via selenium. If there is a google ad you might be able to do something via Options or just click the x.